# Flask gateway equlivent in Django

Tags: python, braintree

I'm setting up my **Braintree** web-hooks in **Django**, as Braintree [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/webhooks/parse/python) says i have to add this method

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, Response
...
def webhook():
    webhook_notification = gateway.webhook_notification.parse(str(request.form['bt_signature']), request.form['bt_payload'])

    # Example values for webhook notification properties
    print(webhook_notification.kind)
    print(webhook_notification.timestamp) 

    return Response(status=200)
```

everything is ok except i have no idea what **gateway** is, and I'm getting *undefined name error*

my Django code

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    print("post:: ", request.POST)

    webhook_notification = gateway.webhook_notification.parse(str(request.form["bt_signature"]), request.form["bt_payload"])
    
    print(webhook_notification.kind)
    print(webhook_notification.timestamp)

    return HttpResponse("Ok")
```

sorry if missed up things, I haven't try **flask** yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not related to Flask nor Django.

It's the [`gateway` object you configure](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/start/hello-server/python) for *any* use of the Braintree Python SDK, á la

```
import braintree

gateway = braintree.BraintreeGateway(
    braintree.Configuration(
        braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
        merchant_id="use_your_merchant_id",
        public_key="use_your_public_key",
        private_key="use_your_private_key",
    )
)
```